# I can not hide Title bar

Tags: java, android

I use this code in manifest for hide title bar, but i cant run my application:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: What error are you running into? Post your Logcat here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a physical device to test your app... Well I tried to hide the NoTitleBar but it became invisible instead!!

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html